# retrieving a byte array from a LONG RAW from oracle db

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to pull data from a long raw field in an oracle 11g database. However I keep getting "specified cast is not valid" when I try:

```
cmd.InitialLONGFetchSize = 1000000;
cmd.AddRowid = true;
byte[] PicTempArray = new Byte[1024];
Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

int i = 0;
while (Reader.Read())
{
   try
      {
      PicTempArray[i] = Reader.GetByte(0);
      }
   catch
      {
      }
   i++;
}
```

I wouldnt be surprised if I was doing a few things wrong. If you didnt guess the LONG RAW is holding some image data. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetByte` is used to retrieve a *single* byte from a numeric column.

You want `GetBytes` instead. You should probably also read the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/B28089_01/featData.htm#i1007197) for "Obtaining LONG and LONG RAW Data".

(As an aside, I hope you don't *really* have an empty catch block - and your code would be more idiomatic if you used camelCase for your local variable names, and outdented the braces for the `try` and `catch` blocks, as they are for the `while` block.)

Comment: Ok awesome, thank you. I tried that before and I made a mistake with one of the parameters. I appreciate you turning me around to try it again.

Comment: What about OLDDB .. Is there an alternative for the InitialLONGFetchSize .. which is not existed

Comment: @Saeed: I don't really understand your comment - but it sounds like you should write a new question.