# Entity Framework SqlQuery Select LONG RAW into byte array

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, oracle11g

I am executing a query in Entity Framework to select LONG RAW data into a byte array.

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<byte[]>("SELECT MESSAGE FROM FOCUS.ENTRIES");
var list = await result.ToListAsync();
```

When I execute this code, I get a list of byte arrays, but all of them are empty. In the database they are not empty.

The MESSAGE table looks like this:

```
  CREATE TABLE "FOCUS"."ENTRY" 
  (  "PRIMKEY" NUMBER, 
     "TITLE" VARCHAR2,
     "MESSAGE" LONG RAW
  );
```

I am using ODP.NET, Managed Driver as DB provider.

I guess it's some mapping problem, but i can't figure it out.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of `FOCUS21.LOGBOOK`? What DB Provider are you using for EF?

Comment: see if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014913/retrieving-a-byte-array-from-a-long-raw-from-oracle-db) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277262/read-image-stored-in-oracle-using-long-datatype) helps you

Comment: @ElmerDantas I have looked at it. The problem is i'm using Entity Framework. The link you provided uses ADO.net..

Comment: as you are working with async method, have you tried to change byte[] for Task<byte[]> ? just wondering...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlQuery expects a `class` with member name equivalent to SQL column.

```
public class MessageInfo{
    public byte[] Message;
}

var result = await db.Database
    .SqlQuery<MessageInfo>("SELECT MESSAGE FROM FOCUS.ENTRIES")
    .ToListAsync();
var list = result.Select( x => x.Message );
```

Few notes from Oracle Docs , https://docs.oracle.com/html/A96160_01/features.htm

> When an OracleDataReader is created containing LONG or LONG RAW types,
>   OracleDataReader defers the fetch of the LONG or LONG RAW column data.
>   The initial number of characters for LONG or bytes for LONG RAW
>   fetched on the client side depends on the InitialLONGFetchSize
>   property of the OracleCommand. By default, InitialLONGFetchSize is 0.
>
> ODP.NET does not support CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess. Therefore,
>   LONG and LONG RAW data can be fetched in a random fashion.
>
> To obtain data beyond InitialLONGFetchSize bytes or characters, a
>   primary key column must be provided in the list of selected columns.
>   The requested data is fetched from the database when the appropriate
>   typed accessor method (GetOracleString for LONG or GetOracleBinary for
>   LONG RAW) is called on the OracleDataReader object.

So try adding primary key and see if you can retrieve data. Otherwise you will have to skip `SqlQuery` and use ODP.NET directly to fetch if you cannot change configuration. Or you will have to create instance of `OracleConnection` and pass it as parameter in your `DbContext`'s constructor.

Comment: @yadejo Have you read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2644572/c-sharp-how-to-get-oracle-long-raw-type-value ?